# Defining a set of prime numbers up to index $m$.

Tags: notation

I want to define a set of prime numbers up to index $m$ as follows
$$P_m=\{p_i:p_1\leq p_i\leq p_m,i\in \mathbb N\}$$
Now, $m=1,2,3,...$ should define the cardinality of this set. I like this compactness but am concerned that the $i\in\mathbb N$ implies that indices across all natural numbers must be chosen rather than stopping at index $m$. I originally did this for more generality such that $m$ can go to infinity. Should I instead define a subset of $\mathbb N$?

Comment: Your notation is not clear.  In writing about primes, it is common to let $p_k$ denote the $k^{th}$ prime.  Thus $p_1=2$, $p_2=3$, and so on.  If so, then your set $P_m$ is precisely the set of the first $m$ primes.   Is that what you intended here?

Comment: I'd just write "Let $P_m$ be the set consisting of the first $m$ prime numbers" or "Let $P_m=\{p_1,\dots,p_m\}$, where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number".

Comment: You could also clarify your definition by giving an example, e.g. $P_3=\{2,3,5\}$.

Comment: @lulu specifically I want $p_1$ to be any prime making $P_m$ a subset of all primes.

Comment: Then your notation is not good.  As you see from the comments, most readers will assume you meant for $p_i$ to denote the $i^{th}$ prime.

Comment: I can't guess what you are trying to define.  Are you saying that you want a sequence of $m$, possibly not distinct primes $\{\psi_i\}_{i=1}^m$  such that $\psi_1$ is the minimum (possibly not unique) and $\psi_m$ is the maximum (again, possibly not unique) but no assumption on the order of the ones in between?  That seems very unusual.

Comment: Keep in mind:  While Brevity is certainly a worthy goal in writing mathematics, Clarity is more important.  You don't want your readers to have to make a long series of guesses to sort out what you mean.  Add some example, write it out in standard English, if possible.